# VBA, Parse end of string, Add custom end to string

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have a path:    Stack/Over/Flow.Ok

I want to Copy this selected cell down X amount of times, but also parse to the '.' or whatever the character is. and add my own customization to the end. So end result:

Stack/Over/flow-addonwhateveriwant.csv

I tried the macro recorder but it seems to be to specific to the cell and what I want to customize the message to.

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution, or a formula?  What exactly are you trying to do? Have `Stack/Over/Flow` in every cell, but have the `.Ok` be different?  `="Stack/Over/flow-"&B1` will be `Stack/Over/flow-##` with `##` being whatever text you have in `B1`...

Comment: `Replace(pathHere, ".Ok", "addonwhateveriwant.csv")`

Comment: @BruceWayne , Yes Bruce, that is a nice work around I didnt think of. So parse the original path's, =Right/left? (A1,LEN(A1),-3)  to take out the .ok, and replace with custom one using &B1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one "." (or whatever your character may be) in your source string, `instr()` and an array might be the easiest solution. Something along these lines:

```
myarray(0)="-addonwhateveriwant.csv"
myarray(1)="-addonwhateveryouwant.csv"
myarray(2)="-addonwhatevereverybodywants.csv"
myarray(...)=...
parsedString=left("Stack/Over/Flow.Ok",instr("Stack/Over/Flow.Ok",".")
For i=lbound(myarray) to ubound(myarray)
    activesheet.cells(i,1)=parsedString & myarray(i)
next i
```

And to be extra cool, you could replace "Stack/Over/Flow.Ok" with something like range("a1").value or "-addonwhatevereverybodywants.csv" with range("c3").value. That way your code can work the next time you have to do this task too.

The macro recorder only gives you just enough information to give you a keyword to search the internet for. Good luck